# Notification not coming on Device but terminal showing Sent Successfully in iOS

Tags: ios7, xcode5, apple-push-notifications

I have added APNS to my app using the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

I followed the exact steps as mentioned in this tutorial but when i sent notification from terminal using SimplePush.php,i got this message
**Connected to APNS.
Message successfully delivered**
But no notification has been received at my end.I have also added my token id and phass-phrase.
Please help.

Comment: this tutorial works perfectly. there must be some issue with the pem file you are creating

Comment: @samfisher but if pem file has some issue then it must not be showing the message successfully delivered

Comment: The PHP script doesn't know if the message was successfully delivered, since APNS doesn't return a response for successful delivery. The only thing "Connected to APNS. Message successfully delivered" means is that there was no error writing the message to the socket. It's possible you used an invalid device token (sandbox token for production push or vice versa) or contacted the wrong APNS server (sandbox instead of production or vice versa).

Comment: @eran this is my production certificate with which i am hitting the server.